# Is HAMPATH in NL/L?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, space-complexity

I know HAMPATH is NP complete problem. But is there a way to tell if it is either a NL or L problem? I tried searching a lot of places online but it feels like I am going nowhere. 
Thanks in advance for any leads

Comment: Hint: NL$\subseteq$P.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know whether HAMPATH belongs to L or to NL. However, since NL$\subseteq$P, if HAMPATH belonged to L or to NL then it would follow that P=NP, which is conjectured not to be the case. So probably HAMPATH doesn't belong to L or to NL.